# Flutter Dialogs do not inherit theme from context

Tags: flutter, dart

I always have to manually wrap the content of my AlertDialog with a Theme widget so that it can inherit the theme of the MaterialApp like this.

```
                       showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext contextPopup) {
                          return Theme(
                            data: Theme.of(context),
                            child: AlertDialog(
                              content: Text('FONT TETST 2'),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
```

## Question

How to make all dialog inherit the MaterialApp theme by default ? Things like fontFamily

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: No bro :( but I found a github issue linked to it

Comment: @TSR do you happen to remember the issue number?